# Lost the ability to use Transformers after migrating to JPA from Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In our legacy Hibernate-dependent code, which I'm converting to JPA, we had one Direct SQL-based query with a transformer.

```
// 1. Create Hibernate Query object
org.hibernate.Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql.toString());

// 2. Run a transformer
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));

// 3. Obtain Result List
List results = query.list();
```

But now that I've converted this to JPA (which is still using Direct SQL), I can't use the Transformer step anymore, because the JPA syntax doesn't support it.

If I omit the Transformer step, I get a case-sensitivity error as follows regarding one of my fields,

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: ID of: USER_T
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1859)
```

Because my UserT object has the field named as `id` (lowercase). My guess is the Transformer is necessary here, but I can't use it with the new JPA syntax.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
org.hibernate.Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql.toString());
query.createAlias("id", "ID")
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));
```

---

from AliasToBeanResultTransformer source example :

```
 *    List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createCriteria(Enrolment.class)
 *          .createAlias("student", "st")
 *          .createAlias("course", "co")
 *          .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
 *                  .add( Projections.property("co.description"), "courseDescription" )
 *          )
 *          .setResultTransformer( new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(StudentDTO.class) )
 *          .list();
```

also you can extend AliasToBeanResultTransformer and overide method transformTuple(). and apply overided transformer for setResultTransformer()